# Unable to connect to AWS Docdb

Tags: errbit

We are trying to connect to `aws docdb` from `errbit`, but of no luck. This is the connection string from docdb:

```
mongodb://user:<insertYourPassword>@dev-docdb-cluster.cluster-xxxx.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?ssl=true&ssl_ca_certs=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&replicaSet=rs0
```

We are able to connect to Atlas db though, the connection string format we are using for atlas is something like this:

```
mongodb://user:pass@cluster-shard-00-00-xxx.mongodb.net:27017,cluster-shard-00-01-xxx.mongodb.net:27017,cluster-shard-00-02-xxx.mongodb.net:27017/errbit?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster-shard-0&authSource=admin&w=majority
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change `config/mongo.rb` file to be as follows:

```
log_level = Logger.const_get Errbit::Config.log_level.upcase

Mongoid.logger.level = log_level
Mongo::Logger.level = log_level

Mongoid.configure do |config|
  uri = if Errbit::Config.mongo_url == 'mongodb://localhost'
          "mongodb://localhost/errbit_#{Rails.env}"
        else
          Errbit::Config.mongo_url
        end

  config.load_configuration(
    clients: {
      default: {
        uri: uri,
        options: { ssl_ca_cert: Rails.root.join('rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem') }
      }
    },
    options: {
      use_activesupport_time_zone: true
    }
  )
end
```

You can notice that this is exactly the same as current one except for I added:
`options: { ssl_ca_cert: Rails.root.join('rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem') }`

It did work for me after doing this :) Of course you need `rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem` file to be present at your Rails root folder.

`wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem`

Yes, I've had to create a docker image with the following code:

```
FROM errbit/errbit:latest
LABEL maintainer="Tarek N. Elsamni <tarek.samni+stackoverflow@gmail.com>"

WORKDIR /app

RUN wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem

COPY ["mongo.rb", "/app/config/"]
```

Comment: Thanks for responding @Tarek , i will give it a shot today. Just curious, did you have to create docker image with this change and how about if i have to upgrade in the future!

Comment: @ArifKhan I've edited the answer to include the docker image I built/used.